# Artificial Hormones of human body

Tags: biochemistry

Can hormones of human body created artificially even i mean the hormones just consisting of bio chemicals and nothing else?

Comment: Human insulin was the first hormone to be artificially made by recombinant DNA technology and marketed  by [Elli Lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eli_Lilly_and_Company).

Comment: Do u know why only insulin is possible until now not other hormones?

Comment: Other hormones have also been made using rDNA technology. Some of which I'm aware of are HCG and GnRH used for Induced breeding of fish. Now humulin synthesised is not exactly the same as natural **hum**an ins**ulin** it varies in certain amino acid sequences.

Comment: Its just out of curiosity that can new hormones be created for the body in order to perform new functions ?